# trying to make a count up timer and it the word "days" isnt showing up

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a count up timer but the word days doesn't seem to want to show up on the screen

HTML

```
<div class="countup" id="countup1">
<div class="yrs"><span class="timeel years">00</span><span class="countupYrs">YRS</span></div> |
<div class="days"><span class="timeel days">00</span><span class="countupDays">DAYS</span></div> |
<div class="hrs"><span class="timeel hours">00</span><span class="countupHrs">HRS</span></div> |
<div class="mins"><span class="timeel minutes">00</span><span class="countupMins">MINS</span></div> |
<div class="secs"><span class="timeel seconds">00</span><span class="countupSecs">SECS</span></div>
                    </div>
```

JS

```
window.onload = function () {
    countUpFromTime("Dec 25, 2021 13:20:00", 'countup1');
};
function countUpFromTime(countFrom, id) {
    countFrom = new Date(countFrom).getTime();
    var now = new Date(),
        countFrom = new Date(countFrom),
        timeDifference = (now - countFrom);

    var secondsInADay = 60 * 60 * 1000 * 24,
        secondsInAHour = 60 * 60 * 1000;

    days = Math.floor(timeDifference / (secondsInADay) * 1);
    years = Math.floor(days / 365);
    if (years > 1) { days = days - (years * 365) }
    hours = Math.floor((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) / (secondsInAHour) * 1);
    mins = Math.floor(((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) % (secondsInAHour)) / (60 * 1000) * 1);
    secs = Math.floor((((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) % (secondsInAHour)) % (60 * 1000)) / 1000 * 1);

    var idEl = document.getElementById(id);
    idEl.getElementsByClassName('years')[0].innerHTML = years;
    idEl.getElementsByClassName('days')[0].innerHTML = days;
    idEl.getElementsByClassName('hours')[0].innerHTML = hours;
    idEl.getElementsByClassName('minutes')[0].innerHTML = mins;
    idEl.getElementsByClassName('seconds')[0].innerHTML = secs;

    clearTimeout(countUpFromTime.interval);
    countUpFromTime.interval = setTimeout(function () { countUpFromTime(countFrom, id); }, 1000);
}
```

I've tried doing

```
<div class="days"><span class="timeel days">00</span><span id="countupDays" class="countupDays">DAYS</span></div>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('countupDays').innerHTML = "DAYS";
```

to add the word days but that did not work because the timer would stop counting

Comment: None of your elements have an id of `element`, so your attempt won't find any elements to update. Which element are you attempting to update?

Comment: @mykaf i used it as an example and realised people would get confused, its updated now

Comment: You have two elements with class="days": `<div class="days"><span class="timeel days">00</span><span class="countupDays">DAYS</span></div>`; the first is the container of your targeted element, so its innerHTML is being updated instead of ".timeel.days"

Comment: FYI: `idEl.getElementsByClassName('years')[0].innerHTML` is not good code for two reasons. 1) [`getElementsByClassName()` should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474) (especially if you aren't actually interested in getting a node list back) and 2) [`.innerHTML` should be avoided](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) (when possible) for performance and security concerns (use `.textContent` instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you had a side effect having the outer element with class `days`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  countUpFromTime("Dec 25, 2021 13:20:00", 'countup1');
};

function countUpFromTime(countFrom, id) {
  countFrom = new Date(countFrom).getTime();
  var now = new Date(),
    countFrom = new Date(countFrom),
    timeDifference = (now - countFrom);

  var secondsInADay = 60 * 60 * 1000 * 24,
    secondsInAHour = 60 * 60 * 1000;

  days = Math.floor(timeDifference / (secondsInADay) * 1);
  years = Math.floor(days / 365);
  if (years > 1) {
    days = days - (years * 365)
  }
  hours = Math.floor((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) / (secondsInAHour) * 1);
  mins = Math.floor(((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) % (secondsInAHour)) / (60 * 1000) * 1);
  secs = Math.floor((((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) % (secondsInAHour)) % (60 * 1000)) / 1000 * 1);

  var idEl = document.getElementById(id);
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('years')[0].innerHTML = years;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('days')[0].innerHTML = days;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('hours')[0].innerHTML = hours;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('minutes')[0].innerHTML = mins;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('seconds')[0].innerHTML = secs;

  clearTimeout(countUpFromTime.interval);
  countUpFromTime.interval = setTimeout(function() {
    countUpFromTime(countFrom, id);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div class="countup" id="countup1">
  <div class="yrs"><span class="timeel years">00</span><span class="countupYrs">YRS</span></div> |
  <div class="days-unique-name"><span class="timeel days">00</span><span class="countupDays">DAYS</span></div> |
  <div class="hrs"><span class="timeel hours">00</span><span class="countupHrs">HRS</span></div> |
  <div class="mins"><span class="timeel minutes">00</span><span class="countupMins">MINS</span></div> |
  <div class="secs"><span class="timeel seconds">00</span><span class="countupSecs">SECS</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, a better approach would be to fix the CSS selection rather than messing with the HTML.  ``document.querySelector(`#${id} > span.days`).innerHTML = days`` removes the ambiguity.

Comment: In this case it's better to fix the ambiguous html, even at the price of changing css as well. This is in order to maintain uniformity. And to prevent ambiguous html.

Comment: Correction: ``document.querySelector(`#${'countup1'} span.days`).innerHTML = days``

Comment: Except the new HTML is patently not uniform.  The `.days-unique-name` element is different to every other element of the counter component.  (But yes, the HTML overall wasn't well designed in the first place - but it wasn't ambiguous.  The selection method being used was)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is really how you're selecting your elements.  Because there are multiple elements with the class `days`, using `getElementsByClass` is returning multiple elements so `idEl.getElementsByClassName('days')[0]` is selecting the `div`, not the `span`.  You could consider removing un-needed classes from your HTML but it's actually perfectly possible to select the correct element with the right selector.

Here is a version that does that (also uses [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) instead of `setTimeout` to avoid having to manually restart the timeout).

```js
var timeoutId

window.onload = function () {
  timeoutId = countUpFromTime("Dec 25, 2021 13:20:00", 'countup1')
};

function countUpFromTime(from, id) {
  const secondsInADay = 60 * 60 * 1000 * 24,
        secondsInAHour = 60 * 60 * 1000;

  const countFrom = new Date(from).getTime();

  // The keys of counter are the class names of the spans that should contain the result of the value method
  const counter = {
    days: (timeDifference) => ( Math.floor(timeDifference / (secondsInADay) * 1) % 365 ),
    years: (timeDifference) => Math.floor(Math.floor(timeDifference / (secondsInADay) * 1) / 365),
    hours: (timeDifference) => Math.floor((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) / (secondsInAHour) * 1),
    minutes: (timeDifference) => Math.floor(((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) % (secondsInAHour)) / (60 * 1000) * 1),
    seconds: (timeDifference) => Math.floor((((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) % (secondsInAHour)) % (60 * 1000)) / 1000 * 1)
  }

  return setInterval( () => {
    let now = new Date(),
        timeDifference = (now - new Date(countFrom));

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(counter)) {
      document.querySelector(`#${id} span.${key}`).innerHTML = value(timeDifference)
    }
  }, 1)
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="countup" id="countup1">
<div class="yrs"><span class="timeel years">00</span><span class="countupYrs">YRS</span></div> |
<div class="days"><span class="timeel days">00</span><span class="countupDays">DAYS</span></div> |
<div class="hrs"><span class="timeel hours">00</span><span class="countupHrs">HRS</span></div> |
<div class="mins"><span class="timeel minutes">00</span><span class="countupMins">MINS</span></div> |
<div class="secs"><span class="timeel seconds">00</span><span class="countupSecs">SECS</span></div>
</div>
```

You could replace the `counter` Object with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and use the result of the selector as the key, but that seems excessively complicated for minor performance gains:

```
    const counter = new Map()
    counter.set(document.querySelector(`#${id} span.days`), (timeDifference) => ( Math.floor(timeDifference / (secondsInADay) * 1) % 365 ))
    counter.set(document.querySelector(`#${id} span.years`), etc etc
    ...

    for (const [key, value] of counter.entries()) {
      key.innerHTML = value(timeDifference)
    }
```